# Get Address String/Lat Lang of tapped location on google maps. API

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am looking for a spc api/method to get the address/Lat Lang of a tapped point in google maps. Basically the need is to allow user to choose location from tapping into the google map.
Once the user taps into a particular location on map, some event should get generated to get the location string as well as lat lang of that tapped place.

Any help/suggestions would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

What you are after is [reverse geocoding](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/#ReverseGeocoding). You pass your latitude/longitude from your click event to the [geocoder javascript object](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#Geocoder) and you will get back the address. So in your click event:

```
geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      if (results[0]) {
          // render the address
```